# Cambiar el color del texto de un node tras pulsar boton

Tags: java, java-swing, interfaz-gráfica

a ver si me podéis ayudar.

Necesito cambiar el color del texto de un nodo en concreto cuando se pulse un botón ya que, ese objeto se pasa añade a un JList y para saber que ya está listado. Así no me genera problemas. Y que cuando esté añadido salga un JOpen Pane diciendo que ya esta.

Este es el código que llevo hasta ahora.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package paquete;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.ListModel;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeSelectionModel;
import paquete.FindCertainExtension.GenericExtFilter;
import classes.FileNode;
import classes.SelectionableTreeNode;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeCellRenderer;



/**
 *
 * @author Usuario
 */
public class Principal extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private SelectionableTreeNode root;
DefaultListModel dlmA = new DefaultListModel(); 
    public Principal() {


    File fileRoot = new File("C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\Test");
    root = new SelectionableTreeNode(new FileNode(fileRoot));
    getList( root, fileRoot);
    Explorador = new JTree(root);
    Explorador.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.DISCONTIGUOUS_TREE_SELECTION);

    initComponents();
     Actualizar();
       }

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel4 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jToolBar1 = new javax.swing.JToolBar();
    ArchivoBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
    AyudaBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
    ContactoBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    btnupdt = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    btnadd = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btndel = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    Explorador = new javax.swing.JTree();
    jPanel5 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jList1 = new javax.swing.JList<>();

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel4Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel4);
    jPanel4.setLayout(jPanel4Layout);
    jPanel4Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel4Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Explorador");

    jToolBar1.setRollover(true);

    ArchivoBtn.setText("Archivo");
    ArchivoBtn.setFocusable(false);
    ArchivoBtn.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    ArchivoBtn.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    jToolBar1.add(ArchivoBtn);

    AyudaBtn.setText("Ayuda");
    AyudaBtn.setFocusable(false);
    AyudaBtn.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    AyudaBtn.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    AyudaBtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            AyudaBtnActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jToolBar1.add(AyudaBtn);

    ContactoBtn.setText("Contacto");
    ContactoBtn.setFocusable(false);
    ContactoBtn.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    ContactoBtn.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    ContactoBtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            ContactoBtnActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jToolBar1.add(ContactoBtn);

    btnupdt.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/refresh.png"))); // NOI18N
    btnupdt.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnupdtActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel1.setText("Label Items");
    jLabel1.setName("lbl"); // NOI18N

    btnadd.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/right.png"))); // NOI18N
    btnadd.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnaddActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    btndel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/left.png"))); // NOI18N
    btndel.setToolTipText("");
    btndel.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btndelActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(btnupdt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(btnadd, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(btndel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addContainerGap(27, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 14, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(9, 9, 9)
            .addComponent(btnupdt)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(btnadd, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 54, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(btndel)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    Explorador.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
    Explorador.setDragEnabled(true);
    Explorador.addTreeSelectionListener(new javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionListener() {
        public void valueChanged(javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionEvent evt) {
            ExploradorValueChanged(evt);
        }
    });
    Explorador.addPropertyChangeListener(new java.beans.PropertyChangeListener() {
        public void propertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            ExploradorPropertyChange(evt);
        }
    });
    jScrollPane2.setViewportView(Explorador);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 350, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 393, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    jList1.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel<String>() {
        String[] strings = { "Introduzca las imágenes que desea mostrar" };
        public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
        public String getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
    });
    jList1.setDragEnabled(true);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jList1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel5Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel5);
    jPanel5.setLayout(jPanel5Layout);
    jPanel5Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel5Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 387, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addGroup(jPanel5Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 387, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel5Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel5Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addGroup(jPanel5Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
    jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
    jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jPanel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(266, 266, 266))
    );
    jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(31, 31, 31)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jPanel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jToolBar1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 899, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jToolBar1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 23, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(217, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void AyudaBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

private void ContactoBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "El servicio no se encuentra disponible en este momento.","Contacto",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}                                           

private void ExploradorPropertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {                                          

}                                         

private void ExploradorValueChanged(javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionEvent evt) {                                        
    DefaultMutableTreeNode selectedNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) Explorador.getLastSelectedPathComponent();

    if(selectedNode != null){
        jLabel1.setText(selectedNode.getUserObject().toString());
    }



}                                       

private void btndelActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    try{
        int index = jList1.getSelectedIndex();
        dlmA.remove(index);
    }catch(Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Debe clickar en una imagen para retirar","Error",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    }



}                                      

private void btnaddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
   dlmA.addElement(Explorador.getLastSelectedPathComponent());
   jList1.setModel(dlmA);

String jTreeVarSelectedPath = "";
Object[] paths =  Explorador.getSelectionPath().getPath();
for (int i=0; i<paths.length; i++) {
    jTreeVarSelectedPath += paths[i];
    if (i+1 <paths.length ) {
        jTreeVarSelectedPath += File.separator;
    }

}
   System.out.println("C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\"+jTreeVarSelectedPath);

  DefaultTreeCellRenderer renderer = (DefaultTreeCellRenderer) Explorador.getCellRenderer();
  renderer.setTextSelectionColor(Color.GREEN);
  Explorador.repaint(); 






}                                      

private void btnupdtActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

  final TreeExpansionUtil expander = new TreeExpansionUtil(Explorador);
  final String state = expander.getExpansionState();
  Actualizar();
  expander.setExpansionState(state);
}                                       

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {



    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        new Principal().setVisible(true);

    });

}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton ArchivoBtn;
private javax.swing.JButton AyudaBtn;
private javax.swing.JButton ContactoBtn;
private javax.swing.JTree Explorador;
private javax.swing.JButton btnadd;
private javax.swing.JButton btndel;
private javax.swing.JButton btnupdt;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JList<String> jList1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel4;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel5;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
private javax.swing.JToolBar jToolBar1;
// End of variables declaration                   


public void getList(SelectionableTreeNode node, File f) {

 if(!f.isDirectory()) {

     // We keep only JAVA source file for display in this HowTo


        SelectionableTreeNode child = new SelectionableTreeNode(f.getName());
        node.add(child);



     }

 else {
     SelectionableTreeNode child = new SelectionableTreeNode(f.getName());
     node.add(child);
     File fList[] = f.listFiles();
     for(int i = 0; i  < fList.length; i++)
         getList(child, fList[i]);


     }




}   

//Método para Actualizar el JTree
public void Actualizar(){

    File fileRoot = new File("C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\Test");
    root = new SelectionableTreeNode(new FileNode(fileRoot));
    getList(root, fileRoot);
    DefaultTreeModel M = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
    M.reload(root);// Actualización del modelo con los datos
    Explorador.setModel(M);// JTree con nuevo modelo de datos
}   

public class GenericExtFilter implements FilenameFilter {

    private String ext;

    public GenericExtFilter(String ext) {
        this.ext = ext;
    }

    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return (name.endsWith(ext));
    }
}

static class CustomDefaultTreeCellRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {
    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean sel, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
        boolean enabled = false; // <-- here is your logic for enable/disable cell

        sel = enabled;
        hasFocus = enabled;

        Component treeCellRendererComponent = super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, sel, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);
        treeCellRendererComponent.setEnabled(enabled);

        return treeCellRendererComponent;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Con este codigo puedes cambiar el icono de los elementos del Jtree. Solo tendrias que hacer una comparacion de lo que te interesa para que solo este sea modificado.\

```
ImageIcon leafIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/pruebasmultiples/emoticon2.jpeg"));
    if (leafIcon != null) {
        DefaultTreeCellRenderer renderer = 
            new DefaultTreeCellRenderer();
        renderer.setLeafIcon(leafIcon);
        arbol.setCellRenderer(renderer);
    }
```